# Hide asp radio button text

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have a asp radio button and i want to set it's visibility to false in javascript.

```
<asp:RadioButton  ID="rad1" Text="my radio button" runat="server" GroupName="b" />
```

I am trying below code in javascript .

```
document.getElementById("rad1").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

But it disables only radio button but the text "my radio button" is visible. I tried setting text , value property to blank text but it didn't work. So how can i hide the text of that radio button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because:

```
<asp:RadioButton  ID="rad1" Text="my radio button" runat="server" GroupName="b" />
```

Is actually rendered to (you can view the source):

```
<input name="b" id="rad1" type="radio" value="rad1">
<label for="rad1">my radio button</label>
```

So if you want to make both hidden you have to do something like:

```
var rad1 = document.getElementById("rad1");
rad1.style.visibility = "hidden";
rad1.nextSibling.style.visibility = "hidden";
```

or an easier approach would be to place the radio button in a `div` for example, something like:

```
<div id="foo">
    <asp:RadioButton  ID="rad1" Text="my radio button" runat="server" GroupName="b" />
</div>
```

and then just do:

```
document.getElementById("foo").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this  by JQuery
First don't forget to add Jquery CDN at your page Header.

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

And the functions will be. 
rdName => is your RadioButton Id

```
$('#rdName').css('display','none');   //Hide Radiobutton.
$('label[For= "rdName"]').css('display','none'); //Hide Radiobutton Text.
```

And You have another solution to drag the radiobutton in a  and give it an Id. then Hide / Show it, then the radiobutton will aslo be hidden and its text.

Answer (score 0):

you should use this type of code to get asp.net controls

```
document.getElementById('<%=rad1.ClientID %>').style.visibility = "hidden";
```

by this you can set visibility to false .

Answer (score -1):

You can use jquery for hiding it,

```
$('#rad1').parent().hide();
```

let me know if it works or not. It should work fine

Comment: First of all he didn't tag it `jquery` and second of all this is just wrong. Why hide the parent? The `radio` button is not nested within a label. What if the parent is the form? Are you going to hide the entire form?