# Radio button not visible in ASP.NET page

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-interface, radio-button, visible

ASP.NET radio button is not visible in my page. I am using it inside ASP.NET `ListView`. I tried putting the radio button inside ASP.NET update panel content template as well. Please tell me what has gone wrong?

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
 <ContentTemplate>
 <asp:ListView ID="FraudCheckList_listView" runat="server">
 <ItemTemplate>
     <p class="fraud-step-title"><%#Eval("question")%></p>
     <div class="row">
    <asp:RadioButton 
         runat="server" 
         class="radio-inline col" 
         GroupName="govt" 
         Text="Low Risk"
    ></asp:RadioButton>
                                                       
    <asp:RadioButton 
         runat="server" 
         GroupName='govt' 
         Text="Medium Risk"
    ></asp:RadioButton>
                                                            
    <asp:RadioButton 
        runat="server" 
        GroupName='govt' 
        Text="High Risk"
     ></asp:RadioButton>
     </div> 
  </ItemTemplate>   
  </asp:ListView> 
  </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: You need to share your code. Without that we cannot guess what's wrong and how to correct.

Comment: Thanks @ChetanRanpariya I have uploaded the code but it does not seem to be css issue

Comment: Are you loading any data into listview?

Comment: Yes. I am loading data from a table datasource.

Comment: Can you share the screen capture of how the ListView look like?

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't shared how your code looks like, i am just assuming certain things. Just see if you have done this or not.

```
void Button_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e){RadioButton.Visible=false;}
```

If incase its true or something your radiobutton will not be visible. In your case it must be hidden. So, make the variable of visible as **false ** So you can just change your code to this and try it out.
This you have to do it in your main code. not in your html code.
Thank You!

Comment: In the Page_Load method, I used RadioButton radio = new RadioButton();
            radio.Visible = false; but it is not making any difference.

Comment: oh sorry. my bad. try radio.Visible = true; does this work?

Comment: could you just update your question showing your html code as well?

Comment: The html page contains around 5000 lines of code, Aadi.I will try to give you the relevant code.

Comment: okay. else just update your question showing the code written with respect to radio button. that can also work

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30160185/radio-button-list-not-display-properly-in-c-sharp . I believe I am facing this same problem.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27329360/hide-asp-radio-button-text. hope you get your answer over here. this might help you